# Setting percentage size on dynamically created fragments within a scrolling layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new to android development so I'm hoping this is a simple question. I'm trying to achieve the following:

- I have an activity that contains a LinearLayout with vertical orientation
- During onCreate I'm loading a list of resources from a service that a user can access, which can be different for each user
- for each resource, i'm creating a fragment of a certain type and adding it to the linear layout via a fragment transaction
- Each fragment should take up 1/3 of the activity's height
- if more than 3 fragments are added, these will be offscreen and can be scrolled to

It's not clear to me how I can set a dynamically created fragment to have a height relative to the screen, but still allow more fragments than the screen can fit. I've looked into setting the weight and weightSum but not sure that will be useful given I want an equal weighting to all fragments.

I've seen code samples that involve setting layout params of the fragment to an instance of LinearLayout.LayoutParams in the fragment's onCreateView(). If the solution involves this, how does one handle the possibility of a fragment being used in a different type of layout? The idea that a fragment needs to know what it's contained in doesn't seem right to me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your points:

- You use dimensions set in the `dimens.xml` file and you override that based on the dpi setting of the device (xhdip, xxhdip, xx... etc.). You can also override by specifying specific screen widths. Taking your margins and padding into account, you divide your available space by 3 and that's your width.
- What you want to do sounds more like using a horizontal scrolling ListView than a ScrollView, but both can be achieved. You'll just have to manually add each View type to the rootView if using ScrollView.
- You don't need to create different fragments for different layouts. You can create a fragment class that you pass the layout file to it in the constructor. You should also use the ViewHolder pattern to simplify the fragment/layout relationships. That way, with some small amount of logic, you can have 1 fragment that handles dozens of different layouts.

The view holder is just a POJO class with public methods/properties; an example:

```
public class MyViewHolder {
    public TextView myTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View rootView) {
        myTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.whatever);
    }
}
```

And you bind it using:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, container, false);
    view.setTag(myViewHolder);
    return view;
}
```

Then you set the view like so:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myViewHolder.myTextView.setText("Hello World!");
    ...
}
```

But here in lies the problem - your view holder is tightly coupled to the fragment because you've exposed public properties, so therefore you would need to create 1:1 relationship between fragment & view holder.

Instead, you should decouple the relationship and contain the logic inside the view holder, using it as an extension of fragment.

```
public interface SomeGenericViewHolder {
    void doSomething();
}
```

The interface is optional, but should be used in this case because it enforces a contract for accessing the contained data.

```
public class MyViewHolder implements SomeGenericViewHolder {
    protected TextView myTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View rootView) {
        myTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.whatever);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        myTextView.setText("Hello World!");
    }
```

Then to build your fragment:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(myViewHolder);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When you say pass the layout file to the fragment in the constructor, I thought fragments should only have a default constructor?

Comment: They don't have to since you're instantiating them yourself, not automatically by the underlying system. If you don't instantiate a fragment, it never exists, unlike an activity, which is instantiated by Intent's